# SAT graph and table interpretation problem

Tags: percentages

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApUsk.jpg

14) Answer is B.

this was my thought process:
It says 30% of the "1-3 Days group" which to me means we want to take 30% of 77. 30% of 77 = 23.1, this number is the total number that should be then redistributed into the 4-6 days group. It will be distributed to all the different colors proportionally. But as far as how many of the 23.1 goes into Cyan is the part I am stuck on.

I tried thinking that of the 4-6 days group 21/52 are Cyan which is about 40%. So I then took 40% of 23.1 = 9.24. Added this 9.24  + 21 = 30.

Thank you.

Comment: sat reading makes me want to die

Answer (score 1):

Work directly with cyan algae that lasts from $1-3$ days. $$16 \times 0.3 + 21$$

Comment about your approach:

The statement "these blossoms are distributed proportionally to the colors" refers to algae that lasts from $1-3$ days.

You can also do $$23.1 \times \frac{16}{77}+21=77 \times 0.3 \times \frac{16}{77}+21$$